# Put excel all cells under each other in one column

Tags: merge, excel-formula, multiple-columns, jquery-ui-sortable

Is there a possibility or formula, to extract all cell data from different columns then putting them under each other just on one column, each cell data just in one cell, therewith I can sort them e.g. from A to Z in one column.

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution 1

Using helper column.

In `Cell E2` enter the following formula

```
=INDEX($A$2:$C$15,MOD(ROW()-ROW($G$2),ROWS($A$2:$A$15))+1,TRUNC((ROW()-ROW($G$2))/ROWS($A$2:$A$15))+1)
```

Drag/Copy down as required.

Then in `Cell F2` enter

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($E$1:$E$45,SMALL(IF($E$1:$E$45<>0,ROW($E$1:$E$45)),ROW(F1)+1)),"")
```

This is an array formula so commit by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. Drag/Copy down as required. Change range as required.

See image for reference.

[image]

---

### Solution 2

Using ugly looking long formula.

Enter the following formula in `Cell D2`

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$15, SMALL(IF(ISBLANK($A$2:$A$15), "", ROW($A$2:$A$15)-MIN(ROW($A$2:$A$15))+1), ROW(A1))), IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$15, SMALL(IF(ISBLANK($B$2:$B$15), "", ROW($B$2:$B$15)-MIN(ROW($B$2:$B$15))+1), ROW(A1)-SUMPRODUCT(--NOT((ISBLANK($A$2:$A$15)))))), IFERROR(INDEX($C$2:$C$15, SMALL(IF(ISBLANK($C$2:$C$15), "", ROW($C$2:$C$15)-MIN(ROW($C$2:$C$15))+1), ROW(A1)-SUMPRODUCT(--NOT((ISBLANK($A$2:$B$15)))))), "")))
```

Drag/Copy down as required. Change range as per you data.

***Note :*** This formula will work only for three or less columns.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

An easier way without using any formula. Just go to **Find & Select**, go **to special**, **select blanks**. All the blanks are now selected go to